# SQL Transactions with Logic Apps and Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way to implement SQL transactions when affecting a single Azure SQL database and several tables, using Azure Logic Apps and the Microsoft SQL Connector ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is not possible to include a SQL Transaction in Logic App flow, presumable to cover multiple Actions, you can still do transactional operations on SQL Server.

The way to do this is with a Stored Procedure which can implement any level of transactionality you need.

One very simple approach would be to load the data into staging tables first, then call a Stored Procedure to transactionally insert the data into the primary tables.  Another option is to use OPENJSON to effectively mimic the Composite Operation feature of the BizTalk SQL Adapter, also in a Stored Procedure.